# Setting listeners on Websocket/RESTful server (AWS Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, https, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a REST/Websocket server that is listening on 8000. I have deployed it on Elastic Beanstalk, but I am unable to connect using the ws:// or wss:// urls.

I can connect to it just fine via https://
with these listeners.

[image: Current listeners]

I've attempted to add a SSH (Secure TCP) listener, but it's still not working (I might be setting it incorrectly).

Note: I'm using a Gorilla Websockets (Golang)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the Load Balancer type to *TCP* and set up an Nginx reverse proxy using *.ebextensions*. Example found [here](https://github.com/anand-io/EBSWebSocketExample/blob/master/.ebextensions/proxy.config)